# In maven project How to download the library in source/binary, mentioned in the <parent> tag in POM file?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

This is the pom file.

```xml
<project>
 <parent>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-api-bom</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <relativePath>../bom/pom.xml</relativePath>
 </parent>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
     <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
     <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I know, to download the dependencies(above its "el-api") we should use

```
mvn dependency
```

But what is the command used to download the parent dependency(i.e weld-api-bom)?

Comment: Just run `mvn clean install`, it will download everything.

Comment: "mvn clean package" please, not install, it has unnecessary side effects. (installing into local repository, which may be sources of problems to new maven users)

Comment: @user2189998 Can you explain what kind of "unnecessary side effects" it has?

Answer (score 0):

Given your parent pom has 
../bom/pom.xml
It could either be downloaded (if avaiable in configured repository) or be read from disk if it there.
In any case most of the maven commands will trigger the download of this artifact as one of the very first steps of the build.

Please also note that "mvn dependency" is not a valid command.